# Drupal 7 not using CloudFront domain to pull images from Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, drupal-7, amazon-cloudfront

I have a Drupal7 deployment using Cloudfront CDN. The Amazon S3 and AWS modules are installed and configured. When I view the site (using a preprod domain) the CDN cloudfront domain is not visible in the image path just the local domain breaking the link to the images.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a Network issue

is now fixed

Thanks